# $facebook->getUser() returning 0 using PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, jquery-ui-dialog, facebook-opengraph

I have just started with the Facebook application development. I downloaded the PHP SDK from Facebook couple of weeks ago.
Following is the first piece of code which i wrote.

```
<?php

   require 'src/facebook.php';
   $app_id = 'My APP ID';
   $application_secret = 'My APP Secret';

   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $application_secret,
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
    echo $uid;
?>
```

But it is always giving me 0 as a result even when i am already login into my facebook account in other tab.
My Canvas URL is pointing to my localhost as i have hosted this app on my local machine only.

I have read almost every post related to this issue but i was not able to solve this issue somehow.. It would be really helpful if anybody could help me in resolving this issue.

Cheers.

Ajay

Comment: Ever got this to work?

Answer (score 1):

The code will always return 0 unless you have authorised the app - even if you are logged into facebook elsewhere. Login to your app by going to the URL outputted by `$facebook->getLoginUrl();`

Then, you will find that `$facebook->getUser()` will return the correct User ID.

Comment: Hey Niraj. Thanks for the reply. i am trying with your suggestion. i am echoing a link with the output of getLoginUrl() as href but it is coming back on to my site without asking me for permissions..

Comment: Did you try following the link echoed out by `getLoginUrl()`?